# Calling a method of another State

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call the determinePosition method in the class below

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    // I want to call this method
    Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {...}
}
```

from the onTap callback of the GestureDetector below

```dart
class CurrentWeather extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<CurrentWeather> createState() => _CurrentWeatherState();
}

class _CurrentWeatherState extends State<CurrentWeather> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
                _determinePosition(); // This method invocation doesn't work
            },
        );
    }
}
```

but that does not work, so how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You should any state managment like provider.

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 1):

that is a very bad practice.
you should use a state management package like Provider or GetX.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that you're trying to call a private method that does not exist in the `_CurrentWeatherState` class.

If you really want this to work without using a seperate library you'll need to give the `_CurrentWeatherState` a way to access the `_HomePageState`.

For this the HomePageState and determinePosition method need to be public (remove the underscore).
You then need to create the HomePage with a [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) so that you can access its state later.
You then pass that GlobalKey to CurrentWeather so that it can access the HomePageState and call the determinePosition method.

```dart
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Wrapper> createState() => _WrapperState;
}

/// This will be used to store the key to [HomePageState] so that in can be passed
/// to [CurrentWeather] so that it can access the [HomePageState].
class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  /// Provides access to [HomePageState].
  late final GlobalKey<HomePageState> homePageKey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // global keys should only be created once, therefore we do it in the
    // initState of a [StatefulWidget].
    homePageKey = GlobalKey<HomePageState>();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        HomePage(
          // create the HomePage with the globalkey
          key: homePageKey,
        ),
        CurrentWeather(
          // pass it to CurrentWeather so that it can access the HomePageState
          homePageKey: homePageKey,
        ),
      ],
    );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

// this needs to be public so that it can be accessed from the outside
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // this also needs to be public so that it can be accessed from the outside
  Future<Position> determinePosition() async {}
}

class CurrentWeather extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrentWeather({required this.homePageKey, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  /// Used to access the [HomePageState] from here.
  final GlobalKey<HomePageState> homePageKey;

  @override
  State<CurrentWeather> createState() => _CurrentWeatherState();
}

class _CurrentWeatherState extends State<CurrentWeather> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        // currentState is nullable so use null aware access
        widget.homePageKey.currentState?.determinePosition();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It would be much easer to use a real [state management solution](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) though.